# Пересылка файлов с Ubuntu в Windows и обратно. VNC использовать обязательно

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vnc

`TightVNC` клиент винды подключается есть функция пересылки файлов. Существует ли такой же клиент для убунту, чтобы была возможность переброски файлов туда и обратно? Чтобы было видно все жесткие и юсб носители? Использовать VNC является обязательным условием. Похоже что-то есть в тимвивер, radmin.

Comment: Ну я пользуюсь `UltraVNC` под wine, чтобы цепляться на доменные машины с авторизацией. Файлы тоже норм кидаются.